# Our Domain Controllers get error when attempting Replication

Tags: networking, dns, relationship, replication, trust

Please help!

We have two domain controllers. For some reason, they stopped replicating in July 2016. Now, when we try to manually initiate replication, we get the following error:

"The directory service cannot replicate with this server because the time since the last replication with this server has exceeded the tombstone lifetime."

Of course this is producing "Trust relationship has been lost with domain controller" issues all over our network as computers and servers can't connect with each other.

One of the suggestions to resolve this has been to demote the domain controllers and bring them back up...which is apparently very complicated.

Is there anything else that can be done to get these two domain controllers to replicate again since it has been so long?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We demoted one of the domain controllers, then re-promoted it, and now everything works fine. Replication is successful.